# How to handle button "up" events across multiple similar buttons.

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winrt-xaml

I have multiple buttons that are using a single command with a command parameter to act on their "down" event among all types of interactions (click, keypress, touch). Turns out this isn't enough for my application, and I must also know when the button is released. How do I do something similar for these buttons "up" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a combination of events are required to listen to:

PointerReleased, PointerCanceled, PointerCaptureLost should all be listened to in a touch environment for "up" events.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the OnIsPressedChanged() method. You may have to derive a class from Button to be able to handle it.

Also, you may handle the MouseLeftButtonUp event, but it will fire only if the button is pressed by a mouse click. If you want to catch keyboard, you will have to process KeyUp events and determine if the the button was clicked as a result of that key (Space, Enter in some cases, a shortcut key, etc.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I see OnIspressedChanged as part of ButtonBase, but this isn't accessible on the stock button.

Comment: Here is an example:   class MyButton : Button
  {
    protected override void OnIsPressedChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnIsPressedChanged(e);

      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntely there's no special command for the UP-event.
But you can use [EventToCommand](http://adammills.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/eventtocommand-action-mvvm-glue/) behavior

Comment: But what event? There's a multitude of up events depending on the input method. I'm looking for something without declaring half a dozen EventToCommand behaviours on each button. There are 12. (It's a telephone keypad)